# Is there any MCMF algorithm in libraries?

Tags: algorithm

The MCMF problem is a standard problem where you have multiple sinks and sources where each source have some supply capacity and each sink node has some demand. Each source and sinks are connected with an edge with some capacity and some cost. You need to maximize the flow with minimum cost. how to solve MCMF problem? Is there any prewritten algo in any library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are couple of algorithms like - capacity scaling, cost scaling, network simlex etc. You can find implementations in libraries like - Boost graph library, Networkx, LEMON.